# ORACLE SQL I need output in three column generation_name , date, total

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

this a table 
[image: this a table values]

expected output as [image]

Comment: can any help me

Comment: Next time, please paste your table data as text instead of showing images. And then also explain your output. BTW: You tagged Oracle 10 and Oracle 11. Which version are you actually using?

Comment: that table output as to be change into 2nd image

Comment: I have understood what you are asking (at least I think so) - otherwise I would not have posted an answer. But your question would have been clearer, if you had said "My table contains date ranges DATE_FROM until DATE_TO. I want to split these rows so as to get one row for every day in the range". Questions need words :-)

Answer (score 0):

if you only want three columns use following statement:

```
SELECT generator_name, from_date Date, total from <your tablename>;
```

If this is not what you are searching, please give more details.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a recursive query:

```
with cte(generator_name, from_date, to_date, total) as
(
  select generator_name, from_date, to_date, total from mytable
  union all
  select generator_name, from_date + 1, to_date, total from cte where from_date < to_date
)
select generator_name, from_date as date, total
from cte
order by generator_name, date, total;
```

Comment: using oracle 12.

Comment: Okay, I've corrected your request tags accordingly. Good luck with my query :-)